# Database not inserting data when trying to upload 2 files in separate rows, nor are files uploading into the set directories, any possible fix?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I came to the conclusion that my last question wasn't very clear.
I am trying to upload two files into 2 different rows in my MYSQL database but when I excecute the code the files don't get uploaded nor do their paths get registered. The query just doesn't excecute at all, it doesn't even insert the data that isn't the files' paths.
Anyways, here is the code for the variables, arrays and the query:

```
if (isset($_POST['bsw'])) {
        $name1 = str_replace("<","&lt;",$_POST['name']);
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $name1);

        $powers1 = str_replace("<","&lt;",$_POST['powers']);
        $powers = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $powers1);

        $weaknesses1 = str_replace("<","&lt;",$_POST['weaknesses']);
        $weaknesses = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $weaknesses1);

        $about1 = str_replace("<","&lt;",$_POST['about']);
        $about = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $about1);

        $available1 = str_replace("<","&lt;",$_POST['available']);
        $available = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $available1);

        $demoFiletype1 = str_replace("<","&lt;",$_POST['filetype']);
        $demoFiletype = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $demoFiletype1);

        $iconDir = "files/uploads/bsw/icons/";
        $iconName = basename($_FILES['icon']['name']);
        $iconTemp = $_FILES['icon']['tmp_name'];
        $iconError = $_FILES['icon']['error'];
        $iconType = explode('.', $iconName);
        $iconActualType = strtolower(end($iconType));
        $iconAllowed = array('png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif');

        $owner = $user->data['username'];
        $ownerId = $user->data['user_id'];

        $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif');

        $demoDir = "files/uploads/bsw/demos/";
        $demoName = basename($_FILES['demo']['name']);
        $demoTemp = $_FILES['demo']['tmp_name'];
        $demoError = $_FILES['demo']['error'];
        $demoType = explode('.', $demoName);
        $demoActualType = strtolower(end($demoType));
        $demoAllowed = array('swf', 'mp4');

        if (empty($name) || empty($powers) || empty($weaknesses) || empty($about) || empty($iconName)){
            echo '<p style="color: red; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px;">Please Fill in All Fields</p>';
        } else {
            if(!in_array($iconActualType, $iconAllowed)) {
                if($iconError === 1) {
                    echo '<p style="color: red; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px;">Invalid filetype, only PNG, JPEG, JPG and GIF are allowed.</p>';
                } else {
                        $iconNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$iconActualType;
                        $iconDestination =  __DIR__ . "files/uploads/bsw/icons/" . $iconNameNew;
                        $iconUpload = move_uploaded_file($iconTemp, $iconDestination);
            if(!in_array($demoActualType, $demoAllowed)) {
                if($demoError === 1) {
                    echo '<p style="color: red; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px;">Invalid filetype, only SWF and MP4 are allowed.</p>';
                } else {
                        $demoNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$demoActualType;
                        $demoDestination =  __DIR__ . "files/uploads/bsw/demos/" . $demoNameNew;
                        $demoUpload = move_uploaded_file($demoTemp, $demoDestination);
                        $fileUpload = mysqli_real_escape_string($iconUpload, $demoUpload);
                if ($fileUpload) {
                    $sql = ("INSERT INTO
                                    bsw
                                    (`bsw_name`, `bsw_about`, `bsw_points`, `bsw_demo_location`, `bsw_power`, `bsw_weaknesses`, `bsw_icon_location`, `bsw_availability`, `bsw_owner`, `bsw_owner_id`, `bsw_type`)
                                    VALUES
                                    ('$name', '$about', '0', '$demoDestination', '$powers', '$weaknesses', '$iconDestination', '$available', '$owner', '$ownerId', '$demoFiletype')");
                    mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error : ".mysqli_error($conn));
print_r($_FILES);
        } else {
            echo "Error uploading files, please try again later.";
}
    }
}
}
}
}
}
```

And here is the form:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px;" type="text" name="name" placeholder="BSW Name"><br>
   <textarea style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px; width: 200px; height: 80px;" type="text" name="powers" placeholder="BSW Powers (seprated by commas)"></textarea>
   <br>
   <textarea style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px; width: 200px; height: 80px;" type="text" name="weaknesses" placeholder="BSW Weaknesses (seprated by commas)"></textarea>
   <br>
   <textarea style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px; width: 250px; height: 80px;" type="text" name="about" placeholder="BSW About (seprated by commas)"></textarea>
   <br>
   <strong>Are you currently available?</strong>
   <select name="available">
      <option name="yes">yes</option>
      <option name="no">no</option>
   </select>
   <br><br>
   <strong>Icons bigger than 100x100 will be rescaled</strong><br>
   <input style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px;" type="file" name="icon"><br>
   <strong>Demonstration (Only supports swf and mp4 filetypes): </strong><br>
   <input style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px;" type="file" name="demo"><br><br>
   <strong>Demo Filetype (Select none if you do not have a demo)</strong><br>
   <select name="filetype">
      <option name="mp4">mp4</option>
      <option name="swf">swf</option>
      <option name="none">none</option>
   </select>
   <br><br>
   <button style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px;" type="submit" name="bsw">Submit BSW</button><br>
</form>
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**
While the help for the prepared statement is great and I really appreciate it, the query is still not getting excecuted due to the file upload script not excecuting first, so I need help on that still as I am quite dumbfounded on that.

Comment: Sorry if I asked it right after my original question, I just realized that I didn't really point out the actual problems I was having !!

Comment: It would be more appropriate to edit your original question if this is just a clarification of that one.

Comment: Looking at your code though, you are not parameterizing your sql which is probably contributing to your issue. You have variables inside single quotes where they will not be expanded into the values they are holding. You are using `mysqli` so it would be a good idea to read up on [bind-param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). If your code is making it through all of those `if` conditions for that sql to fire, then there should be entries in your php log suggesting there was an issue with the sql. That would be the best place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Like JNevill said, since you are using mysqli you should probably use binding parameters:

$sql = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO bsw
                       (bsw_name, bsw_about, bsw_points, bsw_demo_location, bsw_power, 
                        bsw_weaknesses, bsw_icon_location, bsw_availability, bsw_owner, 
                        bsw_owner_id, bsw_type)
                  VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$sql->bind_param("sssssssssis", $name, $about, '0', $demoDestination, $powers, $weaknesses, $iconDestination, $available, $owner, $ownerId, $demoFiletype);

$sql->execute();

// in the bind_param "s" represents "string type", "i" represents "integer type".  By looking at your variables that is the types I assume they are in that order.  Notice the quotes or lack of quotes.

Comment: Thanks, but I still can't figure out how to make the files actually upload which is stopping the query from excecuting. The command just isn't working at all and it needs to actually work for the query to excecute, thank you so much though!

Comment: Are you saying that you're trying to actually upload the file INTO the database?  I don't think you can do that.  I upload files onto the server with reference points in the database to find those files.  If I'm wrong I'm going to learn something from this post.